# Retrieving data after a database query

Tags: c++, sql-server

I have a stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_proc1] (@p_name char(50), @p_age int)

AS

BEGIN

insert into Table_1 (name, age) values (@p_name, @p_age);
select * from Table_1;

END
```

And I have C++ code.

```
    if(SQLPrepare(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLCHAR*)"{call my_proc1(?,?)}", SQL_NTS) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        cout << "success prepare" << endl;
    

    
    SQLCHAR szQuote[50] = "name666";
    SQLINTEGER cbValue1 = SQL_NTS;
    SQLINTEGER cbValue = 0;
    SQLINTEGER nAge = 6666;

    if(SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 50, 0, szQuote, 0, &cbValue1) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        cout << "success bind parameters 1" << endl;


    if(SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, (SQLPOINTER)&nAge, 0, &cbValue) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        cout << "success bind parameters 2" << endl;

    SQLHDESC hIpd = NULL;
    if(SQLGetStmtAttr(sqlStmtHandle, SQL_ATTR_IMP_PARAM_DESC, &hIpd, 0, 0) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        cout << "success get attr" << endl;

    if (SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 1, SQL_DESC_NAME, (SQLPOINTER)"@p_name", SQL_NTS) == SQL_SUCCESS)
    cout << "success set field desk 1" << endl;

    if (SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 2, SQL_DESC_NAME, (SQLPOINTER)"@p_age", SQL_NTS) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        cout << "success set field desk 2" << endl;

    if(SQLExecute(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        cout << "success sql execute" << endl;
    else
        cout << "failed sql execute" << endl;


    //trying to get values from base
    SQLRETURN res = SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle);

    if (res == SQL_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "SQL_Fetch error" << endl;
    }
```

As a result of executing this code, new values are added to the base, I get everywhere success, but only have SQL_Fetch error. That is, INSERT instruction is executed, but SELECT not executed.  What is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First try adding "set nocount on;" as the first statement in the stored procedure. And STOP the laziness. Don't use "select * ..." - specify the columns you want to include in that resultset. If someone adds a column to your table, your code will fail with the current approach. Lastly, do you REALLY want to select every row in the table after adding just ONE row?

Comment: I changed my stored procedure but no has effect. `USE [My_BASE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET NOCOUNT ON

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_proc1] (@p_name char(50), @p_age int)

AS

BEGIN

insert into Table_1 (name, age) values (@p_name, @p_age);
select * from Table_1 where name=@p_name and age=@p_age;
END` and when in code I comment INSERT statement all works fine.

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is a runtime setting that goes inside your stored procedure code. Try inserting it on a line between the `BEGIN` and `INSERT` keywords.

Comment: Thank you, now all work. I read about SET NOCOUNT ON but not clearly understood why without it my code don't work?